# Select the first row after order by using distinct value

Tags: mysql

I have a table named emails which looks like this:

| customer_id | email_template_id | send_time | order_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-10 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-10 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-02-10 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-03-10 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-03-10 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-04-10 | 1 |

I want to order the data by email_template_id which will be given on the web page (can be 1,2,3...). Whenever a person clicks on sort by (template_id = 2), I want to retrieve the data order by template_id then by date, but still get the unique customer_id of course. The result should look something like this:

| customer_id | email_template_id | send_time | order_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-02-10 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-03-10 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-03-10 | 1 |

I have tried this but I am getting duplicate rows.

```sql
select distinct customer_id as cust,order_type,email_template_id,send_time
from email_order 
ORDER by FIELD(email_template_id,2,1,3,4,5,6),send_time desc
```

I tried using subquery to select distinct customer_id

```sql
select distinct(t1.customer_id) from 
(select distinct customer_id as cust,email_template_id 
from email_order
ORDER by FIELD(email_template_id,2,1,3),send_time desc) as t1
```

It works when I only select (t1.customer_id), when ever I select order_type or send_time from t1, it no longer shows unique customer_id, but shows the data according to send_time desc etc

Your help and time will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If your have an older version you can use the query below:

```
    select  customer_id, email_template_id, send_time, order_type 
    from ( select customer_id, email_template_id, send_time,order_type  
    from emails order by case when email_template_id=2 then -1 else email_template_id end ) as e 
group by customer_id;
```

SQLfiddle working on `MySQL 5.6` : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d55f4d/1

But if the version is MariaDB, i think not in your case you should apply limit inside the subquery.
The images below are example in `10.4.17-MariaDB` version

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I really appreciate it, but I think you are missing a small thing. What I want in the output is that when the result is ordered then all the records with similar ids like : email_template_id = 2 will be ordered by send_datetime desc. Similarly all the records with email_template_id = 3 or 1 should be ordered by send_datetime  desc. And one more thing I found that before outer query (with group by customer_id) it shows records in right order but there are a few duplications, but when you apply the outer query with group by it only shows me records with email_template_id = 1 ??

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER` should work well here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                                 ORDER BY FIELD(email_template_id, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6)) rn

    FROM email_order
)

SELECT customer_id, email_template_id, send_time, order_type
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: I am getting this error :                                                                                                   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by customer_id
          ' at line 1

Comment: Either you're not running the code in my answer verbatim (did you leave off the `WITH`?) or you are using a really old version of MariaDB which does not support `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0) "I think I have an old version then" The version is : 10.1.47-MariaDB

Comment: I fount that it's not supported by PhpmyAdmin sql parser. So is there  any other solution?